# Merge or synonymize [getx] and [flutter-getx]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

While editing a question, I noticed that the tags [getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx) and [flutter-getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-getx) both exist and that they refer to the same [package](https://pub.dev/packages/get).

[flutter-getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-getx) has this excerpt:

> GetX is a state management, dependency injection, and route management solution for Flutter. Only related posts should be here.

and [getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx) has no excerpt or tag Wiki at all.

If I'm searching correctly:

- [flutter-getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-getx) has [223](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflutter-getx%5D+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3) Questions, [getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx) has [240](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgetx%5D%20is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3)
- There are [109](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflutter-getx%5D+%5Bgetx%5D+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3) Questions using both tags
- Of [getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx)' questions, [234](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgetx%5D+%5Bflutter%5D+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3) (!) are also tagged with [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter); the other [6](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgetx%5D+-%5Bflutter%5D+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3) are all about Flutter but just not tagged that way.

Based on this data, it seems clear to me that all of these questions are about the same package and I'm proposing they be merged into one, whether it be [getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx) or [flutter-getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-getx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the set of [getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx) questions and made sure that they're all related to flutter-getx, so it was quite clear that both the tags were being used for the same thing. I added [getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx) as a synonym of [flutter-getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-getx), as the tag name was more clear:

[getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getx) (× 240) → [flutter-getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-getx)  (× 224)

I'll merge the tags in a couple of days, just in case there are any issues and we have roll back the synonym.